# UDP client/server send data but can't read

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I'm trying to send data from one application to another over the LAN, I can send the data (sendto returns the number of bytes expected) but I can't read the data. I know that because I'm using select to test the read operation and it returns false. Here is the code used to create the client and the server:

Creating the socket

```
sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)
```

Binding to a port:

```
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr));
```

to send the data to the other machine I use:

```
o_addr.sin_family = family;
o_addr.sin_port = port;
o_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("other_side_ip_address_here");
uint32 sent;    

sent = sendto(sock_fd, data, length, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&o_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))
```

to read the data from the other machine I use:

```
struct sockaddr_in o_addr;
uint32 read;
int l = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
read = recvfrom(sock_fd, data, length, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&o_addr, &l)
```

and to test if there is some data to read I use:

```
int r;
struct timeval tv = { 0, 0 };
fd_set fds;

FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(sock, &fds);

r = select(sock + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

if (FD_ISSET(sock, &fds))
    return true;
return false;
```

The sockets are on block mode, the tests are being performed in two machines.
Thanks for attention

Comment: addr.sin_port = htons(port);
...
o_addr.sin_port = port;

Would expect to use htons() on both ports?

Comment: yes, thanks for helping

Comment: You don't have to explicitly state that a type is a struct like `struct sockaddr_in addr;`), just like you don't write `class string s = "abc";` either.

Comment: It usually doesn't make sense to use `select` in combination with blocking sockets. Usually the reason you use `select` is that you don't want to block. But with blocking sockets, you can't avoid it. So something's not right with your design.

Comment: David, i always use select, i think it is very useful in both cases, blocked or not, i can test if there is something to read just calling one method! isn't this awesome?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: `select()` works just fine with blocking sockets. It can be useful to detect the presence of data before entering a blocking read to receive it. An alternative is to enable `SO_RCVTIMEO` to make a blocking `recvfrom()` exit after a timeout.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But that read can then block, so what's the point? The `select` function is a status reporting function, it can't predict the future. (Expecting `select` to guarantee that a future operation will not block, even though the socket is blocking, has caused vulnerabilities with security implications in the past.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Of course `select()` cannot predict the future, that is not the point. It can only tell you when data is ready to be read. But you could then block on `recvfrom()` until the entire message has been received in full.  In any case, we are talking about UDP here. When `select()` reports the socket is readable, `recvfrom()` will not block since the entire datagram is waiting in the socket's buffer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Unless the implementation decides to discard the datagram, which it has every right to do. You are defending a mistake. Expecting `select` to guarantee that a future operation will not block, even though the socket is blocking, has caused vulnerabilities with security implications in the past. It is a mistake. Status-reporting functions don't come with future guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `bind` call on a receiving socket fails for some reason. Try adding some error checks.

Comment: The first comment on my question gave me the error, i was not calling htons beforing sending a message, so it was sending a message to an unknown port. thanks anyway